# python how to add new key in dictionary with range function

Tags: python

This is json file:

```json
[
  {"name": "Saeed"},
  {"name": "Joseph"},
  {"name": "Mary"},
  {"name": "Peter"}
]
```

I'm going to iterate over it and then add a new key called `id` for each one, and its value is unique.

This is my current for loop but does increment the first item only:

```
import json

with open('db.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
for i in range(1, len(data) + 1):
    for d in data:
        d['id'] = i
        break
```

Current output:

```py
for i in data:
{'name': 'Joseph', 'id': 4}
{'name': 'Mary'}
{'name': 'Peter'}
{'name': 'Saeed'}
```

Expected output is:

```
{'name': 'Joseph', 'id': 1}
{'name': 'Mary', 'id': 2}
{'name': 'Peter', 'id': 3}
{'name': 'Saeed', 'id': 4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for the id value.

```
i = 1
for d in data:
    d['id'] = i
    i += 1
```

Comment: Suggestion: `for i, d in enumerate(data, start=1): d['id'] = i`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `break`. The correct code is:

```
import json

with open('db.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    d['id'] = i + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but did you test? When I run, I see the `id` value of all is `4`.

Comment: You are right. I've just edited with an improved solution using `enumerate`

Comment: `enumerate` has a `start` parameter, you can use this instead of the `+ 1`